# How can I change the value of label(in class Window) from class Szymon and display it in the window?

Tags: java, swing, variables, label

I am a beginner in Java so don't be harsh in the answers please. I am trying to boost up my java skills by trying to code relatively hard-for-me programs but this one got me stuck.

```
public class Szymon {

    public static void reply(String name) {

        switch(name){
        case "michal":name="Niedzwiedz!";
              break;
        default:System.out.println("wot ?");
        }

     }

    public static void greet(String name){
        System.out.printf("Elo %s co tam u ciebie ? \n",name);
    }


}
```

I spent hours writing this and even though it isn't a lot I got a whole lot of experience from it.

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class Window<label> extends JFrame{
       private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

       public Window(){
           super("Display of Input & Output");
           setSize(600,400);
           setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


           JPanel p= new JPanel();


           JButton b= new JButton("reply()");
           final JTextField tf=new JTextField();
           tf.setColumns(10);
           JButton b2= new JButton("greet()");
           final JTextField tf2=new JTextField();
           tf2.setColumns(10);
           final JLabel label=new JLabel();


           p.add(b);
           p.add(tf);
           p.add(b2);
           p.add(tf2);
           p.add(label);

           new Szymon();

           b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                  String tfVal = tf.getText();
                  Szymon.reply(tfVal);


               }
            });
           b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                   String tf2Val=tf2.getText();
                      Szymon.greet(tf2Val);
               }
            });

           add(p);

       }





}
```

Comment: You don't. Send the response back to the caller and change the value there

Comment: can you show me an example of how this would look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to modify the caller from within the method you are calling, which is an issue of over extending responsibility, instead, return the value that should be applied by the caller...

```
public class Szymon {

    public static String reply(String name) {
        switch(name){
        case "michal":name="Niedzwiedz!";
              break;
        default:name = "wot ?";
        }
        // Return the value to be applied...
        return name;
     }

    public static void greet(String name){
        System.out.printf("Elo %s co tam u ciebie ? \n",name);
    }
}
```

Then when you call the method, apply the change on the return...

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        String tfVal = tf.getText();
        String reVal = Szymon.reply(tfVal);
        label.setText(reValue);
    }
});
```

For example...

Comment: Thanks a lot , now I just need to change the location of some J- stuff and I'm done.